# Python Function Reference Object Attributes

Tags: python

How do I pass a function to an object that accesses attributes in the object's scope?

This works:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, some_func):
        self.some_func = some_func
        self.stats = 'some stats'
    def execute(self):
        return self.some_func()
def bar():
    return x.stats      
x = Foo(bar)
x.execute()
```

but I dislike that I have to write a new `bar` if I rename the object.

What I actually want to write is more like:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, some_func):
        self.some_func = some_func
        self.stats = 'some stats'
    def execute(self):
        return self.some_func()
def bar():
    return self.stats      
x = Foo(bar)
x.execute()
```

and have the `self` in `bar()` pick up stats from any Foo object it get's passed to, regardless of how it's named. I can't figure out a smart way to do this.

Are there good ways to reference attributes of Foo objects without changing Foo? Alternately, could you enable this by making Foo's call to `some_func()` smarter? Does this vary between python 2 and 3?

Comment: Won't both these approaches throw a NameError?

Comment: Why not add a "caller" parameter to `bar`?  Basically the same thing that `self` would normally do.  (You could even name it `self` if that makes the code more clear)  `def bar(caller): return caller.stats`  `def execute(self): return self.some_func(self)`

Comment: No. The first example with `x.stats` works as written, although not if you try to call `some_func` in `__init__`. I've inherited code that makes calls like this and I think it's clowny.

Answer (score 4):

Why can't the object be passed in at runtime?

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, some_func):
        self.some_func = some_func
        self.stats = 'some stats'
    def execute(self):
        return self.some_func(self)

def bar(self_):
    return self_.stats      

x = Foo(bar)
x.execute()
```

The above function `bar()` works because in python nothing is really private as long as you know the name of an attribute.

Comment: This seems to be a much better way than using an `eval` function, you could also instead pass in the `stats` themselves as a parameter but this seems much cleaner.

Comment: I don't actually control `Foo`, I only control `bar()`. I can ask for changes to `Foo`, and this would be a relatively lightweight one in that it would only require everyone else who uses `Foo` to trivially rewrite their own `some_func` functions by accepting `self_`. Many other people use Foo, and what they are doing with `some_func` may not require `stats` or `self`.

Comment: You do have additional options: If you only have a small number of functions that rarely change their name, you could monkey patch each instance of `Foo` with additional functions like `bar()`. You can create your own class which instantiates a `Foo` (or has one passed into `__init__()` and forwards unknown method calls to the `Foo` instance.